# What's the best replacement for TinyMCE.dom.Event.add?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, tinymce

I'm migrating an old custom 3.2.5 theme to 4.1.10 in TinyMCE.
In TinyMCE 3.X there's was a function to attach events to elements being

`dom.Event.add(target_id, event, callbackFn)`

Now in 4.1.10, the Event.add is deprecated. I read that I should be using DOM.bind, but in the **TinyMCE old themes** (3.X) I saw, they were passing the editor.id + '_path_row' (among others) instead of only the editor ID. Why is that? When I tried to search for those objects in the DOM, they didn't exist.

Why would they try to attach an Event by passing an element that doesn't exist?

I tried doing DOM.bind(editor.id, 'click', callbackFn); but didn't work getting the following error:

> Cannot assign to read only property ...

The only way it worked was by passing the entire editor object.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best and most secure way to achieve something similar is to assign an eventListener to the editor body directly:

```
editor.getBody().addEventListener('click', callbackFn, false);
```

For those who use jQuery:

```
$(editor.getBody()).bind('click', callbackFn);
```

Comment: Yea, but what about editor.id + '_path_row' thing? why would they pass the editor.id plus that path_row string? that target doesn't even exist

Comment: i do not know the answer to that myself